# How to get GCC version supports specific feature?

Tags: c++, gcc

There are cases that I want to know since which version of gcc a specific compiler flag or c++ language feature is supported so that I can write compile control preprocessors in source files or in CMakeLists.txt. For example, the compiler flag -wno-missing-field-initializers is not supported in gcc 3.4.3(an ancient version I have to use), but I want to know exactly since which version does gcc support that flag. Where can I find such instructions?

Comment: I'm not aware of a listing of when particular features were added, but GNU maintains [an extensive collection of GCC manuals](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/) on-line, dating back to v2.95.  The information you want can be gleaned from there.

Comment: There is this https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html

Comment: Is this question about how to use cmake to check if you have the flag or where to find the documentation? Where to find documentation is typically outside the scope of SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check specific flags using `CheckCXXCompilerFlag`

For example,

```
include(CheckCXXCompilerFlag)
CHECK_CXX_COMPILER_FLAG(-Wno-missing-field-initializers RESULT_OF_TEST)
```

Although a more portable option, across compilers, is to use  `CMAKE_CXX_KNOWN_FEATURES`

See https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_gbl/CMAKE_CXX_KNOWN_FEATURES.html